# C# Send parent form data to child form

Tags: c#, forms

Trying to get this active in another form. I want the objects from listBox1 to go to the labels: label3 and label4 in form2. PropertyA should assign to label3 and PropertyB to label4. It will simply load the data from form1. The question is in the form2 code. When an item is selected form the listbox it will write the properties for prepare them for the next form2 instance.
Most of this is fairly short and simple code...

Made a simple program to illustrate...

FOUND THE SOLUTION.... SEE FORM2, it was a problem of casting between forms the listbox1.SelectedItems as object of SpecialClass type.

Class

```
 namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    class SpecialClass
    {
        public string PropertyA { get; set; }
        public double PropertyB { get; set; }

        #region [Methods]
        public override string ToString()
        {
    return string.Format("PropertyA: {0}, PropertyB: {1}", this.PropertyA, this.PropertyB);
}
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Form1

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void AddBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SpecialClass o = new SpecialClass();
         o.PropertyA =  textBox1.Text;
            o.PropertyB = double.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            listBox1.Items.Add(o);
         }

        #region [Currently unused methods]
        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        #endregion

        private void openNewForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Form2 form2 = new Form2(this);
            form2.Show(this);   
      }

        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SpecialClass o = ((ListBox)sender).SelectedItem as SpecialClass;
            label3.Text = o.PropertyA.ToString();
            label4.Text = o.PropertyB.ToString();



        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Form2

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        Form1 form1Data = new Form1();
    public Form2(Form1 _form1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        form1Data = _form1;
    }

          private void label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            SpecialClass oF2 = form1Data.listBox1.SelectedItem as SpecialClass;
            label3.Text = oF2.PropertyA.ToString();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```